# How to get faster at 3x3

Tags: rubiks-cube, speedsolving

I am new to speed cubing and would like to figure out how to get faster at cubing based on my personal stats.

Which aspect should I focus on? Which principles would be the most useful for me (lookahead or any other concept)? And, any fingertricks I should know for faster rotation (especially for M/M')?

Target speed: sub-25 to sub-35

Current record: 51 sec

Current average: 1 min 05 sec

Turns per second: 2.2

Cube: Original Rubik's brand

Method: F2L + Beginners method for Yellow and Final

Time breakdown: 5-8 seconds for cross; 30-40 second for F2L; 10-15 seconds for yellow orientation; and 10-15 for finishing the last layer.

I can use PLL for case H and 
OLL for these:[image]

EDIT: Thanks for all the responses, everyone! I got a MF3RS2 and Cubicle Weight 5 for Christmas, and it's better than I hoped for. I learned full 4LLL plus a bunch of extra algs (Y, Ja/b, T/P/C-shapes) and worked on TPS to get my average down to sub-40 with a record of 28. I also found J-Perm's Cross + F2L videos incredibly helpful, and I'm trying to get that stage to sub-15.

Can't wait for my first comp in February (Bremium Cubing 2019); looking to be sub-30 by then.

Happy cubing!

Comment: I'm just gonna slap [this cube](https://www.walmart.com/ip/Dayan-ZhanChi-3x3x3-Stickerless-Speed-Cube/433287854?wmlspartner=wlpa&selectedSellerId=0&adid=22222222227106206762&wmlspartner=wmtlabs&wl0=&wl1=g&wl2=c&wl3=222661337900&wl4=pla-361329665656&wl5=9001953&wl6=&wl7=&wl8=&wl9=pla&wl10=117019096&wl11=online&wl12=433287854&wl13=&veh=sem) right here. My personal favorite, and dirt cheap at that. 

Also, make sure to buy some lubricant. When your cube starts to slow down,  lube that bad boy up and watch your fingers fly, and your times drop.

Answer (score 5, accepted):

Here are some tips although the number 1 improvement will always come from more practice. I'v gone through this process and my PB is now just over 16 seconds.

- Get a speed-cube! It doesn't really matter which one, but it will allow you to turn faster without worrying so much about the alignment. The Valk and Gan cubes are very popular. My personal favorite is MoYu WeiLong GTS2 M.
- Learn 2-look OLL and PLL. There are 7 cases for the OLL corners and 7 for PLL. That should allow you to get down to around 12 seconds for the Last Layer.
- It's good that you have already started F2L. Practice these a lot. Don't worry about memorizing a whole bunch of algorithms for all the cases. There are really only 3 basic patterns you need to know as you have probably figured out. Focus on being able to insert them without looking once you have identified where they are. This will help you be able to search for the next pair while you are inserting them. Look ahead comes slowly with lots of practice.

Just working on these improvements is enough to get you down to the range you're looking for. The next step after that would be learning the 21 cases for 1-look PLL. That shaves off another 3 seconds or so at that point.

Hope this helps. Remember to have fun!

Answer (score 1):

Agreeing with StevenWhite , buying a new speedcube is a must.
Try the online stores of speedcubeshop or the cubicle.us for it.

Visit this forum , and there will be a lot of resources put up regarding , how to improve , on your already beginner knowledge of the last layer of a 3x3.

[Speedsolving](https://www.speedsolving.com/)

Try and watch this video , and adopt the newer and faster , last layer beginner approach.

[Video tutorial](https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=0WbU8ValM_Q)